# vscode print too much log on terminal

Tags: logging, visual-studio-code

```
--- Truncated to last 15 messages, set outputCapture to 'all' to see more ---
Fri, 10 Jul 2020 03:31:38 GMT express:application set "subdomain offset" to 2
Fri, 10 Jul 2020 03:31:38 GMT express:application set "trust proxy" to false
Fri, 10 Jul 2020 03:31:38 GMT express:application set "trust proxy fn" to [Function: trustNone]
Fri, 10 Jul 2020 03:31:38 GMT express:application booting in development mode
Fri, 10 Jul 2020 03:31:38 GMT express:application set "view" to [Function: View]
Fri, 10 Jul 2020 03:31:38 GMT express:application set "views" to '/Users/yilikun/test/logOutput/views'
Fri, 10 Jul 2020 03:31:38 GMT express:application set "jsonp callback name" to 'callback'
Fri, 10 Jul 2020 03:31:38 GMT express:router use '/' query
Fri, 10 Jul 2020 03:31:38 GMT express:router:layer new '/'
Fri, 10 Jul 2020 03:31:38 GMT express:router use '/' expressInit
Fri, 10 Jul 2020 03:31:38 GMT express:router:layer new '/'
Fri, 10 Jul 2020 03:31:38 GMT express:router:route new '/'
Fri, 10 Jul 2020 03:31:38 GMT express:router:layer new '/'
Fri, 10 Jul 2020 03:31:38 GMT express:router:route get '/'
Fri, 10 Jul 2020 03:31:38 GMT express:router:layer new '/'
Process exited with code null
/usr/local/bin/node /Users/yilikun/test/logOutput/index.js
Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:53698/1af20b06-4623-4f24-9595-14c0d872809a
For help, see: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector
Debugger attached.
```

when I debug with setting:

```
{
  // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
  // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
  // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "Launch Program",
      "program": "${workspaceFolder}/index.js",
    }
  ]
}
```

please help me, I have been troubled by this problem for a long time.
i had google it and look for help in github issues.
oh my god, i  can not post this problem.
Got same issue with same vscode version but on mac.

Answer (score 4):

```
    {
        "type": "node",
        "request": "launch",
        "name": "nodejs",
        "program": "${file}",
        "outputCapture": "std"
    }
```